# How to close webview from running on close? JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

```
 Platform.runLater(() -> {
            WebView wv = new WebView();
            final WebEngine engine = wv.getEngine();
            fxpanel.setScene(new Scene(wv));
            engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            engine.load(Url);
        };
```

and when I close this frame when this `WebView` is open I can see them is running in the background, so I try to close it like this in one public void class but it is not close properly so how can I do it.

```
   public static void closeframe() {
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    if (ClassName != null) {
        ClassName.frame.dispose();

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            wv = new WebView();
            ClassName.wv.getEngine().reload();

            ClassName.wv = null;
            ClassName.frame = null;
        });
```

Comment: what happened when you tried   wv.getEngine().getLoadWorker().cancel() ?

Comment: i try that to nothing happend the frame is close but i can herd the music in background singing so the webview is not close in the engine

Comment: Try the following webView.getEngine().load(null);

Comment: i try this to u can see the code up there

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? The error is not in code you have posted (so either there's a bug, or the error is in other parts of your code...)

Comment: i update the code in closeframe , so thats is how i close it

Answer (score 1):

exit PlatForm in stop Method Like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    //Entry point to application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent authScene = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/Auth.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(authScene);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Green Project : Login Form");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont what to close the application from run only the webview

Comment: and its not Extends Application its extends javax.swing.JFrame from where i close the webview and webview is showing in the public class

Comment: so use Platform.exit(); where you need to end the web Engine work!